Is it appropriate to use the following sentence for someone who is dead already? "He is not a philosopher as he is usually believed to have been"
Is it appropriate to use the following sentence for someone who passed away long time ago?

He is not a philosopher as he is usually believed to have been.

The subject of my sentence was a mysticist (Mevlana) who passed away years ago. So,does my sentence, with this tense structure, give the impression that he is dead already?

I would expect was and not is.

Do people still believe that he was a philosopher?

See also this question.

We've had this king of question already.  I just can't find it.

It's idiomatic to use the present tense when writing about an author, even a deceased one: "Aristotle speaks of the self-sufficient man ..."  --  but only in the context of their work, not when the subject is biographical in nature, where one would normally use the past or, very sparingly, the historical present.  Your sentence could admit the present if the context is the man's output.  But if it's because people have a historical fact wrong, that philosophical works have been misattributed to him, then not.  But if it is the former and you do use the present, use it in both clauses.

@Centaurus This contrasts well with the present perfect, which is famous for its lifetime effects. E.g. "Shakespeare has written 38 plays" or "The Romans haven't built Stone Henge". Also why it's a good question (i.e. precisely because this is not true of present simple constructions)

This question is answered at What tense to use for a dead person's permanent contributions. However, in this case, the historic present would not sit well alongside 'as he is usually believed to have been'; the past simple is the sensible choice here. // My 'leave closed' vote doesn't seem to have registered.

@TimR 60 000+ hits in a Google search for "Plato is a philosopher". Ditto for Socrates.  But certainly there shouldn't be the disconnect between 'is [not]' and 'is ... believed to have been'.

@EdwinAshworth .  I don't find the sentence "Plato is a philosopher" particularly idiomatic, and if one wrote it  in an encyclopedia article (one that was not in a crowd-sourced encyclopedia) an editor would most likely change it to "was".   But if the sentence went on to say "who writes that the sublunary world is not reality"  then it would fall into the "works" context I referred to in my earlier comment.

Compare "Plato is a philosopher who puts his poetic skills to philosophical use in the Phaedrus and elsewhere..." (Philosophical Religions from Plato to Spinoza, Carlos Fraenkel) and "Plato is a philosopher for whom reality differs from the way in which it presents itself to us in perceptual experience and must be rationally discovered (Oxford Handbook of Plato, ed.Gail Fine)

@TimR Context is certainly paramount (and OP seems to strongly imply framing context). 'When the general public are categorising famous men of the past, Locke is a philosopher, but Voltaire is an author. As for Mevlana? He is not a philosopher as he is usually believed to have been.' Biographical in nature. (I don't see how 'author' and 'philosopher' can not be connected with work.)

@EdwinAshworth  I inadvertently left off an -s- off  of works in the topmost comment. When speaking about the works of a writer, dead or alive, individually or collectively, it is SOP in academic prose to use the present tense. Biographical details, on the other hand, are usually dealt with as history, the past tense predominating, sometimes historical present.I didn't know where the OP was taking that sentence and didn't want to assume. The sentences from the two books I quoted above begin with what looks to be a biographical detail (the person's occupation) and yet use present tense.

But they immediately become statements about Plato's works. The first book, Philosophical Religions..., explicitly mentions the Phaedrus and "elsewhere", whereas the Oxford Handbook...  offers in that sentence a succinct summary of Plato's thought drawing from multiple unnamed works, but the allusion is clearly to Plato's thought, not to a biographical detail like where he was born, say, or who his pupils were.

One can find strings such as "Napoleon is a typical dictator'. I'd say 'idiomatic ... but only in the context ...' is too prescriptive. A rule of thumb coming across as a rule.

@EdwinAshworth Napoleon is not a relevant example. The question is about a philosopher, someone who wrote about the human experience, broadly speaking, and that has been the focus of my comments-- writing about writers.

[The historic present, used ...] 'but only in the context of their work, not when the subject is biographical in nature' seems rather more general.

No, it  is not, for two simple reasons, both of which suggest this belongs not here in SE English Language Usage but rather, in English Language Learners.
Firstly, dead or alive 'He is not a philosopher as he is usually believed to have been' could never work in English. Supporting details belong to ELL…
If it did work, that phrase could never either suggest or deny that the subject was dead…
